# Partition by datetime Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, partitioning

**Situation**:
I want to load ~5B records on a Google BigQuery table. I have a field called 'date_time' that describes the record datetime (from 2012 to today). I would like the BigQuery table to be partitionned on this field.

**Complication**:
I am streaming  all the records to the BigQuery table and it seems that only the last 12 months record are accepted by BigQuery for the partition.

**Question**:
I have read the instructions (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables) but I still don't understand how to stream data in a way that would allow partitioning/indexing on my 'date_time' field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current streaming limitation are defined in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables)

> You can stream data between 1 year in the past and 6 months in the future. Data outside of this range is rejected. When the data is streamed, data between 7 days in the past and 3 days in the future is placed in the streaming buffer, and then it is extracted to the corresponding partitions. Data outside of this window (but inside the 1 year, 6 month range) is placed in the UNPARTITIONED partition. When there's enough unpartitioned data, it is loaded to the corresponding partitions.

As suggested in this [answer](http://Looks%20like%20duplicate%20of%20this%20https://stackoverflow.com/a/49250772/1031958) by @Felipe you should stream your data to a non-partition table and use the copy/load actions to move it to your partition table

Note: You are only paying on streaming insert only so no extra cost is involved in such a workaround